Error with "statistics" data action in Experience Builder
A user reported an issue with an Experience Builder app (ArcGIS Enterprise 11.3). The "statistics" tool within the Table widget doesn't seem to be working - an error message shows up whenever the user selects a field.

It looks like this issue is occurring for multiple layers in different apps within our organization. We found that the issue only occurs for referenced data...the statistics tool works fine with hosted data or Living Atlas layers.
Has anyone had the same problem and found a solution?

can you open this app in EDIT mode and check if the widget works there and is configured correctly?

@YogeshChavan The widget has the same problem in Edit mode (live view) and is configured correctly as far as I can tell.

Is this specific to this particular layer in this web map? Can you try any other map with other data in the widget?

@YogeshChavan This error is occurring for multiple different layers in multiple different apps in our org.

Can you reproduce this behavior with sample data (cities, states) available by default in portal?

@YogeshChavan Great question! Just tried with the US County Boundaries layer from Esri, and I'm not getting the error.

Means, its specific to the data you are working with, can you compare both the fields in states and your data for any null values, data type diff(these do not make a huge difference, but still), or something else? Also, can you try exporting your data once and testing again by re-publishing on Portal?

FYI: We ended up opening a ticket with Esri support and they confirmed that this is a bug affecting the Table and Map Layers widgets - hopefully it will be fixed in an upcoming release.
